# IE 11 sends different User-Agent header to different subdomains

Tags: internet-explorer, http, http-headers, user-agent, internet-explorer-11

Well, I've been working on an User-Agent based shared-session protection between subdomains.

I was extremely surprised that it's been working well until IE 11 preview was released recently. There are 2 subdomains

**example.com** and **sub.example.com**

I've intercepted requests to both domains and it seems that USER-AGENT HTTP Header being sent to each domain is different.

Request to example.com has:

> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0)
>   like Gecko

Request to sub.example.com has:

> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2;
>   .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media
>   Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BRI/1; MS-RTC LM 8; rv:11.0) like
>   Gecko

Do you have any idea what is the reason for this strange dynamic behavior?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Microsoft has the site in question configured to use UA-spoofing (via the Compatibility View list) and that causes IE to send a custom UA string.

CompatView-based UA spoofing was enabled in IE8 in 2008:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/08/27/introducing-compatibility-view.aspx

And in IE10+, it's gotten richer, with per-site spoofing to enable the best experience. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/09/21/internet-explorer-11-user-agent-string-ua-string-sniffing-compatibility-with-gecko-webkit.aspx for an exploration of this topic.

Comment: Hi Eric and thanks for the answer. I'm not entirely convinced but this indeed might be the reason. I'll check if I can disable that

Comment: @EricLaw: That was my first reaction too, but note that it's sending the same version number to both servers.  Both those UAs are `rv:11.0`; neither is "the legacy IE7 User-Agent string".

Comment: In IE11, the Compatibility View List feature was made richer, and allows per-site compat hacks. For instance, if you look at the UA string when loading go.microsoft.com, the UA string is "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0"

Answer (score 10):

Official Microsoft Documentation on MSDN:

- [Compatibility changes in IE11](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [User-agent string changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Quotes:

> For many legacy websites, some of the most visible updates for IE11 involve the user-agent string. Here's what's reported for IE11 on Windows 8.1:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

> Here's the string for IE11 on Windows 7:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

> *In rare cases, it may be necessary to uniquely identify IE11. Use the Trident token to do so.*

Isn't it nice, they say "like Gecko"? ;)