# Internet Explorer 11-Only Code

Tags: internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to insert a code for a website client of mine that works specifically for IE11, which is producing a DIV in the wrong manner (but not in any other browser).  When I fetched the browser to display in the browser, IE11 said Mozilla 5.0...what?

I'm using:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Trident/7.0; rv:11.0') !== false) {
echo '<div style="position:relative; top:-15px;">';
  }
```

[non IE code]

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Trident/7.0; rv:11.0') !== false) {
echo '</div>';
  }
```

Help?

Answer (score 0):

This may help.

IE 11 has user agent strings changed and that is the reason why you see  MOzilla/5.0 when you output the browser user agent string. For more information

[IE 11 sends different User-Agent header to different subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005832/ie-11-sends-different-user-agent-header-to-different-subdomains)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx